# Many to many and Many to One relation in Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a scenario
where 
many persons belong to many business and
many persons belong to many sub business

Also 1 business may have many sub business

I am done with the part where 1 business belongs to many sub business

For the Persons entity where we have 2 many to many business I am looking for a join table with following structure

Join Table name: person_business

Join Table Fields : person_id,business_id,subbusiness_id

What I am doing is

```
 /**
     * Business
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "buslvlone", inversedBy = "id")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name = "person_business")
     */
    private $businesses;

    /**
     * Sub Business
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "buslvltwo", inversedBy = "id")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name = "person_business")
     */
    private $subbusiness;
```

But when I run to update schema from console I get Error
"The table with name 'advocacy_business' already exists."

Comment: You didn't write any question.
Your mapping is wrong. By both properties, the content of "inversedBy" should be the name of the property in the preson_business entity, relating back to your person entity.

Comment: Just update the question..I need to tackle such a scenario with Symfony

Comment: The error is that you have two entities with the annotation  * @ORM\Table(name="advocacy_business")

Comment: Thanks that did the work

Comment: OK I write it as answer. Please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two entities using the same annotation :

```
/** @ORM\Table(name="advocacy_business") */
```